# JBoss: Error while deploying the war

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am fairly new to the JBoss. Getting following error while deploying the war. Not sure where to look at to fix it.

```
    service jboss.module.service."deployment.myProject.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.myProject.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:92) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: config:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:949) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1304) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1332) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:226) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:71) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]`
        ... 5 more
```

Using JBoss EAD 6.1 with JDK 1.6

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <module-alias name="myProject"/>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
            <subsystem name="ejb3" />
            <subsystem name="jca" />
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
            <subsystem name="cdi" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.antlr" />
            <module name="asm.asm" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.beanutils" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.dom4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" />
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.envers" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-jaxrs" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc" />
            <module name="org.javassist" />
            <module name="javax.inject.api" />
            <module name="org.jboss.as.logging" />
            <module name="javax.transaction.api" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jettison" />
            <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.springframework.spring" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Can u Please add your jboss-deployment-structure.xml ??

Comment: Do you have any dependency defined for modules?

Comment: Updated with `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` content.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav were you able to find a solution to this? I'm having a similar problem.